# Apache Ant: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, selenium, ant, junit

I am trying to run  a selenium test case file written in java using  [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). To setup this configuration, i followed   [this tutorial.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/running-tests-with-ant.html)

below is my ant config in build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <project name="Hello World Project" default="info">
   <target name="info"> 
  <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath>  
      <pathelement path="lib\junit-4.10.jar" />
    </classpath> 
    <test name="com.lo.test.selenium.AssignCampaignTestCase"  haltonfailure="no" outfile="result"> 
      <formatter type="plain"/>
      <formatter type="xml"/> 
    </test> 
  </junit>
</target>
</project>
```

**But it is showing error like :**

```
          Testsuite: com.lo.test.selenium.AssignCampaignTestCase
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
        Caused an ERROR
    com.lo.test.selenium.AssignCampaignTestCase
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lo.test.selenium.AssignCampaignTestCase
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
```

Test case code in **AssignCampaignTestCase.java**

```
    package com.lo.test.selenium; 
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartWriter;


/**
 * @author Ashutosh
 *
 */
 public class AssignCampaignTestCase {
     private static ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("global-messages");
    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //Make it static in order to make one instance of this class(helps to avoid opening of 2 browsers at once)
    @Test
    public void campaignEmailTestCase() throws InterruptedException { 
        AssignCampaignTestCase emTesObj=new AssignCampaignTestCase();  
        // CommonMethods commonMethods=new CommonMethods();
        String fName="test LO";
        Integer LeadId=570903;
        String campaignName="2GetMoreLeads"; 
        String SubjName="Welcome to your 5-day challenge and tips";   //NOTE: No problem,Type without double quotes. It will work for you 
        doLogin(driver); 
        emTesObj.goToLeadsListPage();
        emTesObj.searchByFirstName(fName);//without this also,it will work but Gives you the correct navigation on UI
        emTesObj.waitBeforePageLoads(LeadId.toString()); //pass the Id attribute which you aspect to see after the page is loaded
        emTesObj.assignCampaign(LeadId, campaignName);  
        emTesObj.readRecentEmail(SubjName);  
    }


     //shows you the leads List Page     
     public void goToLeadsListPage(){ 
         driver.get("http://www.xxxxx.com/orderManagement/xxxx.action");
     }
       .................
       .................
       .................
```

***Here is my project structure::::***

[image]

Please help me to run my project using Ant.

Comment: Please anyone help me. I was trying to run this since 3hrs. Still i am unable to run  this program using Ant.

Comment: It look like ur build.xml not able to load com.lo.test.selenium.AssignCampaignTestCase class.

Comment: The tutorial you mentioned has : "In the classpath element I add the output locations of my project code, and test code. In other words, the directories where my compiled code + test code is located." your classpath has only the path to junit.jar - add the path to the bin folder of your eclipse project.

Comment: @Rebse What do you mean by "add the path to the bin folder of your eclipse project"

Comment: @Rebse Did you mean to add `<pathelement path="bin\" />` ??

Comment: <pathelement location="path/to/bin"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding selenium jar file in you classpath. Currently you only added junit.

Comment: i added this line "<pathelement path="lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar" /> " but it showed me  error like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig`

Comment: You have to add selenium jar and all other dependencies that selenium is using.

Comment: Is it possible to keep all these jar under 1 folder and instead of adding linking one on 1 line . Can i do something like this `<pathelement path="solLiv/" />`           ???

Comment: try
    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="<path to jar files>">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

and then in your junit test target 
  <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
      

    </junit>